# how do i resolve old eclipse version crashing on open?

Tags: java, eclipse

so im trying to get an older version of eclipse but when i lauchh i just get this error in the logs:

```
!SESSION 2021-12-04 17:55:27.808 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20090611-1540
java.version=1.8.0_301
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-12-04 17:55:29.106
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Collator.<clinit>(Collator.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.initialize(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.internalBasicInitialize(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$26.runWithException(Workbench.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3855)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
    at com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:191)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69)
    ... 28 more
```

i tried searching it on youtube and google but it came with useless results
can someone help me?

Comment: any special reason you want to use an older version of eclipse? with many possibilities, if your Operating System has performed updates recently.

Comment: How are you starting eclipse? from the original Start menu launcher? Desktop shortcut? Have you tried reinstalling that older version of eclipse from the installer executable?

Comment: Java 6 would have been the current version of Java when Eclipse 3.5.0 was released, it may need to be run with that.

Answer (score 1):

A **bug** in the com.ibm.icu plugin/bundle prevents you running Eclipse Galileo (3.5) with **Java 8 update 301** (version: 1.8.0_301) which only occurs **when** the **update is greater than 255**.

As **workaround** you might run your **retro Eclipse with** a **retro Java** like [jdk8u252-b09.1](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/tag/jdk8u252-b09.1). Please note that such old software contains **known vulnerabilities**.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the ecipse version you are trying to launch, but at a first sight, it seems that the eclipse version is too old to run under java 8. Try an older java version too or a newer eclipse version

Comment: The build id says it is Eclipse 3.5.0 (Galileo) and, yes, it probably is too old to run with Java 8